# iPad app crashing with no crash log while reading from file

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, file-io

The basic structure of my program has the user select an item from a UITableView, which corresponds to a stored text file. The file is then read into an array and a dictionary, where the array has the keys (I know I can just get the keys from the dictionary itself, this isn't my question).

The view is then changed to a UISplitView where the master view has the keys, and the detail view has the items in the dictionary attributed to that key.  In this case, it's a series of "Yes/No" questions that the user selects the answer to.

My problem is this: When I click on a cell in the UITableView (first screen), it works fine, the data is read in perfectly, and so on.  When I go back to the UITableView and click on the same cell again, the program crashes. Here is the read-in-from-file method:

```
-(NSArray *)readFromFile:(NSString *)filePath{
    //  NSLog(@"Path was: %@", filePath);
    NSString *file = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    //  NSLog(@"File was: %@", file);
    NSScanner *fileScanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:file];

    NSString *held;
    NSString *key;
    NSMutableArray *detailStrings;
    NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *details = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    /**
    This is where the fun stuff happens!
    **/
    while(![fileScanner isAtEnd]){
        //Scan the string into held
        [fileScanner scanUpToString:@"\r" intoString:&held];
        NSLog(@"Inside the while loop");
        // If it is a character, it's one of the Key points, so we do the management necessary
        if ([[NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[[held lowercaseString] characterAtIndex: 0]]){
            NSArray *checkers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[held componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"]];
            NSLog(@"Word at index 2: %@", [checkers objectAtIndex:2]);

            if(detailStrings != nil){
                 [details setObject:detailStrings forKey:key];
                 [detailStrings release];
            }
            NSLog(@"After if statement");
            key = [checkers objectAtIndex:2];
            [keys addObject:(NSString *) key];
            detailStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        else if ([[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[[held lowercaseString] characterAtIndex: 0]]){

            NSArray *checkers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[held componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"]];
            NSLog(@"Word at index 1: %@", [checkers objectAtIndex:1]);
            [detailStrings addObject:[checkers objectAtIndex:1]];
        }
     }
     NSLog(@"File has been read in");
     [details setObject:detailStrings forKey:key];
     NSArray *contents = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSMutableArray *) keys, (NSMutableDictionary *) details, nil];

     [detailStrings release];
     return contents;
}
```

I've determined that the program crashes inside the

```
if(detailStrings != nil)
```

statement.  I figure this is because I'm missing some memory management that I am supposed to be doing, but don't have the knowledge of where it's going wrong.  Any ideas as to the problem, or why it is crashing without giving me a log?

Comment: Why do you check if `detailStrings` is `nil`? It obviously is: you never assigned a value to it before the if statement. Or did I miss something?

Comment: What is the call stack or the reason why it crashes?

Comment: After further thinking, I guess you have a freed pointer, `detailStrings`. Redefining it doesn't make it `nil`.

Comment: The idea behind checking if detailStrings was nil was a rather misguided idea that releasing it set it to nil.  However, I didn't consider that the memory that the pointer was pointing to wouldn't be nil.  AKA I am an idiot. The more you know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`detailStrings` is not initialized when you enter the `while` loop. When you declare `NSMutableArray *detailStrings;` inside a method, `detailStrings` is not automatically set to `nil`. So when you do

```
if ( detailStrings != nil ) { .. }
```

it enters the if statement and since it is not initialized, it will crash when you access `detailStrings`.

Another thing is that `detailStrings` won't be initialized if it enters the `else` part of the loop first. That will cause a crash too. So based on your requirement, either do

```
NSMutableArray *detailStrings = nil;
```

or initialize it before you enter the `while` loop.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that every newly defined variable is automatically nil. You can test it yourself by putting a breakpoint after the definition and then getting the value if the variable. It will be equal to 0x0 (nil). Unless the variable has been used elsewhere — that's why it's not a bad idea to nil values when not needed anymore (when race conditions may occur in your code).

Comment: Problems arise only if the variable is already defined — which is probably the case here. A free pointer, one might say. The solution is indeed assigning `nil`.

Comment: @Randy Marsh: I *know for a fact* that newly defined variables in Objective-C are NOT automatically nil. If they are class member variables, they are, because `alloc` clears out the memory it allocates, but other memory allocation, such as stack variables like `detailStrings` just get the value of whatever happens to be on the stack.

Comment: This is the correct solution and highlights the importance of setting an object to nil after releasing it.

Comment: Thank you very much, and now I've learned an important lesson.

Answer (score 2):

Deepak said truth. You should initialize detailStrings with nil first.

But there is second possible issue:

I recommend also to set nil after release, because in the next loop you may test nonexistent part of memory with nil.

```
if(detailStrings != nil){
            [details setObject:detailStrings forKey:key];
            [detailStrings release];
            detailStrings = nil;
}
```

And the third possible issue: depending from incoming data you may go to the second part of IF statement first time and try to addObject into non-initialized array.

The fourth (hope last): you have memory leak with "checkers" arrays

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'm seeing:

```
//read in the file
NSString *file = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
//create the scanner
NSScanner *fileScanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:file];

//declare some uninitialized stuff
NSString *held;
NSString *key;
NSMutableArray *detailStrings;

//initialize some stuff
NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *details = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

//begin loop
while(![fileScanner isAtEnd]){
    //scan up to a newline
    [fileScanner scanUpToString:@"\r" intoString:&held];
    //see if you scanned a lowercase string
    if ([[NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[[held lowercaseString] characterAtIndex: 0]]){
        //make an array
        NSArray *checkers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[held componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"]];

        //do a check... against an uninitialized value
        if(detailStrings != nil){
            //set a potentially uninitialized value into an array with an uninitialized key
            [details setObject:detailStrings forKey:key];
```

At this point, you're pretty much hosed.

The fix:

- properly initialize your variables
- run the static analyzer
- read the memory management programming guide

Comment: Reading the guide now.  Thanks for looking at it!